# Laravel Mix LESS compilation fails at Google Font import

Tags: webpack, less, laravel-mix

I have some LESS files that I want to compile with Laravel Mix. However it crashes at Google font import.

This import:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho);
```

fails with this message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-4!./resources/less/adminto.less
Module build failed: 

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution.

```
@import (css) url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700)
@import (css) url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700)
@import (css) url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho)
```

Also, in your webpack.mix.js file, do not forget to reference your LESS source and destination.

```
mix.less('resources/less/app.less', 'public/css/');
```

Then try running your npm command `npm run dev` , `npm run watch` or `npm run prod`

Hope this helps